# I'm using docker desktop with kubernetes and I'm trying to create some pods but I've noticed a syntax error in the yaml

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, docker-desktop

I'm using docker desktop with kubernetes and I'm trying to create some pods but I've noticed a syntax error in the yaml file can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or if there's any extra configuration before creating the pods

follow my file: **01-nestjs.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.18.8
    ports:
      - port: 3000
    spec:
      containers:
       name: api-gateway
        image: nestjs/cli:latest
        env:
         name: NODE_ENV
          value: "production"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: default
```

meu error:

```
error: error parsing ./01-nestjs.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Comment: `containers` is supposed to be a list, not a mapping.

Comment: @larsks How is my container code? thank you

Comment: `name:` (line 12) is indented one space less than the lines below it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I did the test but it gives the same error thank for reply

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML definition looks like a mix of `Endpoint` and `Pod` which can not work. I suggest you to check [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#using-pods) for basic examples from which you can derive and experiment.

Try with this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
spec:
  serviceAccountName: default
  containers:
  - name: api-gateway
    image: nestjs/cli:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    env:
    - name: NODE_ENV
      value: "production"
```

Comment: I managed to create a pod, I just wanted to know how I put my site with host and IP to access the files. Do I need to create a container first before kube? Thank for reply

Comment: Check Kubernetes documentation for Services (they can expose Pods outside of the cluster, depending on their types) and you may also want to create a custom docker image (Search for Dockerfile and you may want to derive from Nginx image most probably, if your application is served as static or .js files) containing your site / application and serving it up. You may want to search for guides to set everything up as it will require some effort. If you are searching for something more easy, you may want to check Heroku

Comment: I managed to make it work by looking at the documentation thank you..